# Firebase Database Connection Permanently

Tags: android, firebase

I have implemeted Firebase SMS authentication, do I always have to verify that the Firebase database is connected on Android Studio everytime becuase sometimes it only connects when I click on Tools -> Firebase -> Authentication -> Email and password authentication (it will automatically change from "Not connected" to "Connected"), do I need to keep Android Studio open 24/7 when I go live to ensure that the database remains connected at all times?

Comment: You don't have to connect that every time, as long as you have implemented the library in the gradle with proper call of the methods.

Comment: thanks, I will monitor and observe this overtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better clarification to my comment, Android app is always compile based on the `gradle` configuration.  Therefore, you don't have to repetitively connect it every time as you have implemented the code in your `gradle` previously.